# Why isn't Gradle picking up on my Android module dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I'm trying to create a multi-module project for the first time in IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle. I've spent an hour reading the docs and various tutorials and SO-questions without being able to solve this simple case. My structure:

```
-Project
   |-vg
   |-vgcommon
```

`vgcommon` is an Android Gradle Module, while `vg` is an Android Gradle Application (technically also a module).

- `vg` depends on `vgcommon`
- `vgcommon` builds
- `vg` does not, as all the classes from `vgcommon` are "not found".

Here are my gradle.build files and setup.gradle. Can anyone see what I do wrong?

**settings.gradle** (root level)

```
include ':vgcommon', ':VG'
```

**vgcommon\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1+'
}
```

**vg\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputFile = file("../build/publish/app.apk")
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom compile
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':vgcommon')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/spring-appsensor-android-1.7.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/spring-util-android.jar')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:1.0.2'
    provided 'junit:junit:4.11'
    // Next 2 Just to make IntelliJ happy:
    provided 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    provided 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4+'
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/defaultFlavor/debug")
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    unitTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
    }
}

task unitTestDisplayResults << {
    toOpen = projectDir.toString() + "/build/reports/tests/index.html"
    println "Opening page: " + toOpen
    ("cmd /C start " + toOpen).execute()
}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
    finalizedBy unitTestDisplayResults
}
```

**Error ouptut excerpt:**

```
:VG:generateDefaultFlavorDebugSources
:VG:compileDefaultFlavorDebugJava FAILED

C:\source\VG\src\main\java\com\myapp\errorhandling\VgErrorHandler.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vgcommon module is defined as an application module, not a library. In its **build.gradle**, instead of this line:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

use this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

Comment: Thanks. Note to others: Also remove 'productFlavors'-section, as there is no such thing for libraries.